# Mysql connection string how to set +03 timezone?

Tags: mysql, time, timezone, database-connection

Hi I am using mysql version 8, and I am trying to add gmt +03 timezone in my conneciton string, however on internet I  could nothing about it. 
I tried some strings as below:

```
{url}:3306/{schemeName}?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=+03
{url}:3306/{schemeName}?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=GMT+03
{url}:3306/{schemeName}?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=GMT+3
```

None of them had worked.
Thank you,,

EDIT: I an using this in a Spring boot project, application.yml file.
The error I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No timezone mapping entry for ' 03'
```

Comment: In which programming language is this used? Looks Java..

Comment: @RaymondNijland please see the edit.(It is java)

Comment: The most simple is using a query directly after connecting with `SET SESSION time_zone = '+03:00'` or even `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+03:00'`

Comment: try this `serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

Comment: @LukeKroon that is worked! I think I shpuld use time zone names as this, rather than sth gmt+03

Comment: From your profile, it appears you are in Turkey? If so, you should use `"Europe/Istanbul"`.

Comment: @MattJohnson yes I have used it after Luke says abput moscow I have figure out Istanbul :)